# Android - How to check if User has seen message or not

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a chat application. So, I wanna know how can check if the user has seen the message or not?  I have no idea how can I implement it.

Here is my Firebase Database Structure

[image]

I followed a tutorial but it doesn't work. And I didn't understand the logic either.

**Here is the Code.**

```
ValueEventListener seenListener;
private void seenMessage(String friendId) {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message")
                .child(userId + " - " + friendId);
        
        seenListener = db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Chats chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chats.class);
                        if (chat.getReceiverID().equals(userId) && chat.getSenderId().equals(friendId)) {

                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("isSeen", true);
                            dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**And In Adapter Class**

```
        if (position == mList.size() - 1) {
        if (messages.isSeen()) {
            holder.seen.setText("Seen");
        } else {
            holder.seen.setText("Delivered");
        }
    } else {
        holder.seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**Activity Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");

    intialiseVariables();

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayout.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userId = user.getUid();
    mList = new ArrayList<>();


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    friendPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("firendPhoneNumber");
    username.setText(name);


    sendMedia = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(userId).child("Sent");
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    databaseReference.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(friendPhoneNumber).
            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        friendId = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        displayDetails(friendId);
                        readMessage(userId, friendId);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

    send.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
        sendMessage(message, "text");
        genrateChatList();
    });
    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isShown) {
            cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isShown = false;
        } else {
            cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isShown = true;
        }
    });
    gallery.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        chooseImage();
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on how can I implement it?

Comment: seenMessage is simply a function is called whenevr you open the chat activity with spcific friend id. It calls the function on seenMessage and in seenMessage function first check the seen property in node . and then update it. just like in whatsapp messaenger or anyother

Comment: @HasnainSabir So, the code is correct?

Comment: yes this seenMessage fucntion is correct

Comment: @HasnainSabir But the textview never changes from delivered to seen.

Comment: where are you calling this seenMessage Function can you show the snippet

Comment: @HasnainSabir I am calling it on onCreate while passing the userId with whom currently I am chatting.

Comment: try to call this function onResume method and show the activtiy code. if it is still not showing

Comment: @HasnainSabir Still not working I have added onCreate code.

Comment: just make sure your friend id is getting your are correct

Answer (score 0):

i hope this answer is helpful for you :

When a message is sent to a user with a `socket`, it is in the `seen = false` state, and as soon as it is received from the `socket`, a notification (new message) is displayed to the user in Android, but it is still in the `seen = false` state. When the user opens the relevant chat page and the received message is displayed to the user in `recyclerView` or `linearLayout` or ..., the mode changes to `seen = true` and it sent to the server with a `socket`.

Comment: Actually, I am not using socket.

Answer (score 0):

you should check while received a message, is that receiver on activity or fragment?
if is true, the message can be seen by the receiver.
while messages data loaded for the user, that is meaning of message Displayed by the user, Then it must be seen.

```
  socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            if (getActivity() == null)
                return;
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        String senderID = data.getString("sender");
                        String receive_id = data.getString("receive_id");
                        String message = data.getString("message");
                        String senderNickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
                        String replybyid = data.getString("replybyid");
                        String replybytext = data.getString("replybytext");
                        String getid = data.getString("id");
                        String gettime_created_at = data.getString("time_created_at");
                        String getfile = data.getString("file");
                        String getdate = data.getString("time_created_at");
                        String getdocument = data.getString("document");
                        String getstatus = data.getString("status");
                        String getforward = data.getString("forward");
                        String profile = data.getString("profile");
                        if (!senderID.equals(Hawk.get("token_id")) && receive_id.equals(Hawk.get("token_id").toString())) {
                            SenderMessage message1 = new SenderMessage();
                            message1.setSender("0");
                            message1.setReceiver("1");
                            message1.setId(getid);
                            message1.setBody(new MyApplication().decrypt(message));
                            message1.setTime(gettime_created_at);
                            message1.setFile(getfile);
                            message1.setDocument(getdocument);
                            message1.setReplybyid(replybyid);
                            message1.setDate(getdate);
                            message1.setReplybytext(replybytext);
                            message1.setStatus(getstatus);
                            message1.setForward(getforward);
                            message1.setProfile(profile);
                            message1.setIsSeen(1);
                            if (receive_id.equals(Hawk.get("token_id"))) {
                                socket.emit("isseen", 1, senderID, receive_id);
                            }
                            senderMessages.add(0, message1);
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                            } else {
                                v.vibrate(500);
                            }
                        }

                        messageAdapter.setSelectedItem(0);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you update the value in the database, but never update `isSeen` in your messages adapter?

After you run this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("isSeen", true);
dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
```

The correct value is in the database but it won't automatically update the textviews. So after you update the value in the database, you should notify the adapter of a change at the given position of the message.

Once you have the position of the message in the adapter, you can set the text, and call something like the following:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) // <-- position is the position of the message in the adapter
```